# Counting rows until a condition is met in R - NAs before the condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

First of all, I'm somewhat new to R and I'm having a trouble managing some time series data. I found a solution which works (Code below), but is awfully slow on larger datasets (35min for 1 variable on 750k rows).

What I'm trying to achieve is that for every time `USAGE` value is over some pre-defined value (`usage_limit`) it starts counting the rows until it's over the same value again, when it resets the counter. For each client it starts with NA and is NA until it passes the `usage_limit`, when the counter is changed to 0. If NA now shows up in `USAGE` when the counter has already been changed to 0, it counts normally. Or in simpler terms, I'm trying to create a variable which shows how many rows (or in my case months) in the past `USAGE` was over the `usage_limit` by user.

This is the dummy data and expected output and loop used for calculating `USAGE_35PCT_MTH`. This is done on R 3.5.1, lubridate 1.7.4 and tidyverse 1.3.0

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dummy_tb <- tibble("USER_ID"=c("000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "200000", "200000", "200000", "200000", "200000", "200000", "200000", "200000"),
                   "REFERENCE_DATE"=c("31.01.2016", "29.02.2016", "31.03.2016", "30.04.2016", "31.05.2016", "30.06.2016", "31.07.2016", "31.08.2016", "30.09.2016", "31.10.2016", "30.11.2016", "31.12.2016", "31.01.2017", "28.02.2017", "31.03.2017", "31.03.2014", "30.04.2014", "31.05.2014", "30.06.2014", "31.07.2014", "31.08.2014", "30.09.2014", "31.10.2014"),
                   "USAGE"=c(0.30, 0.35, 0.34, 0.38, 0.40, 0.70, 0.78, 0.95, 0.36, 0.22, 0.11, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, NA, 0.36, 0.2, NA, 0.2, 0.2, NA, 0.2),
                   "USAGE_35PCT_MTH"=c(NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

dummy_tb$REFERENCE_DATE <- as_datetime(dummy_tb$REFERENCE_DATE, format="%d.%m.%Y")
dummy_tb$REFERENCE_DATE <- as_date(dummy_tb$REFERENCE_DATE)

dummy_tb <- dummy_tb %>%
    arrange(USER_ID, REFERENCE_DATE) %>%
    mutate("USAGE_35PCT_MTH"=NA)

counter <- NA
user_curr <- ""
user_prev <- ""
usage_limit <- 0.35


for (row in 1:nrow(dummy_tb)){
    user_curr <- dummy_tb[row, "USER_ID"]
    if (user_curr != user_prev ) {
        counter <- NA
    }

    checking_value <- dummy_tb[row, "USAGE"]

    if (!is.na(checking_value)){
        if (checking_value >= usage_limit) {
            counter <- 0
        }
    }
    dummy_tb[row, "USAGE_35PCT_MTH"] <- counter
    counter <- counter + 1
    user_prev <- user_curr 
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to speed this up? I've been trying to figure out a way with Dplyr, but haven't struck gold yet.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

dummy_tb %>%
  #Replace `NA` with 0
  mutate(USAGE = replace(USAGE, is.na(USAGE), 0)) %>%
  #Group by USER_ID
  group_by(USER_ID) %>%
  #Create a new group which resets everytime USAGE is greater than usage_limit
  group_by(temp = cumsum(USAGE >= usage_limit), add = TRUE) %>%
  #Create an index
  mutate(out = row_number() - 1) %>%
  group_by(USER_ID) %>%
  #Replace with NA values before first usage_limit cross.
  mutate(out = replace(out, row_number() < which.max(USAGE >= usage_limit), NA))
```

which returns :

```
#   USER_ID REFERENCE_DATE USAGE USAGE_35PCT_MTH temp out
#1   000001     31.01.2016  0.30              NA    0  NA
#2   000001     29.02.2016  0.35               0    1   0
#3   000001     31.03.2016  0.34               1    1   1
#4   000001     30.04.2016  0.38               0    2   0
#5   000001     31.05.2016  0.40               0    3   0
#6   000001     30.06.2016  0.70               0    4   0
#7   000001     31.07.2016  0.78               0    5   0
#8   000001     31.08.2016  0.95               0    6   0
#9   000001     30.09.2016  0.36               0    7   0
#10  000001     31.10.2016  0.22               1    7   1
#11  000001     30.11.2016  0.11               2    7   2
#12  000001     31.12.2016  0.01               3    7   3
#13  000001     31.01.2017  0.10               4    7   4
#14  000001     28.02.2017  0.10               5    7   5
#15  000001     31.03.2017  0.10               6    7   6
#16  200000     31.03.2014  0.00              NA    0  NA
#17  200000     30.04.2014  0.36               0    1   0
#18  200000     31.05.2014  0.20               1    1   1
#19  200000     30.06.2014  0.00               2    1   2
#20  200000     31.07.2014  0.20               3    1   3
#21  200000     31.08.2014  0.20               4    1   4
#22  200000     30.09.2014  0.00               5    1   5
#23  200000     31.10.2014  0.20               6    1   6
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem and reduced the time from ~35mins to 4 seconds. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add an addendum, which I didn't specify in the first question. While Ronak Shah's anwser worked wonderfully for the initial problem, I had an issue where a `USER_ID` had all `NA` values throughout the `data.frame`. In Ronak's anwser it would normally count from 0 to the number of rows a user had.
I wanted to have `NA` values in such case. I just added a few lines to fulfill this requirement.

```
library(dplyr)

dummy_tb %>%   
    #Replace `NA` with 0   
    mutate(USAGE = replace(USAGE, is.na(USAGE), 0)) %>%   
    #Group by USER_ID   
    group_by(USER_ID) %>%  
    #Create a new group which resets everytime USAGE is greater than usage_limit
    group_by(temp = cumsum(USAGE >= usage_limit), add = TRUE) %>%   
    #Create an index
    mutate(out = row_number() - 1) %>%
    group_by(USER_ID) %>%
    #Replace with NA values before first usage_limit cross.
    mutate(out = replace(out, row_number() < which.max(USAGE >= usage_limit), NA)) %>%
    #Ungroup to reset grouping
    ungroup() %>%
    #group by USER_ID again
    group_by(USER_ID) %>%
    #check if all USAGE values are NA by USER_ID
    mutate(out_temp = all(is.na(USAGE))) %>%
    #replace where out_temp == TRUE
    mutate(out, replace(out, out_temp, NA))
```

edit:

Similarly there was an issue if `USAGE` never crossed `usage_limit`. It normally counted the months, which should've been NA, since `USAGE` never crossed `usage_limit`. I added another similar check as previously, just if all `temp` values by `USER_ID` are `0` as this means it never changed values it also never crossed `usage_limit`.

at the end added these lines

```
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(USER_ID) %>%
    mutate(out_temp = all(temp==0) %>%
    mutate(out, replace(out, out_temp, NA)) %>%
    ungroup()
```